# Why I am getting this errors in React Table - Cannot read property 'col11bDataExpanded' of undefined - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am working with React Table. This is my Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/m5nn9ko90p

I am trying to get the rowindex of some specific columns in my Table.

I am getting the index properly but I am getting this errors when I click on columns 11a and 11b:

> Cannot read property 'col11aDataExpanded' of undefined
>
> Cannot read property 'col11bDataExpanded' of undefined

Can you kindly look into this problem and update my CodeSandbox by getting rid of this issue.

Comment: Please distill your code down to a [Minimal, Verifiable and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - currently there is far too much code for us to try to figure out what's going on there.

Comment: I looked at it.  I don't even see the error that you're talking about.

Comment: I also see no errors running your sandbox.  Do you have a repro?

Comment: @Ryan Shillington You will see the error when you click on columns 11a and 11b

Comment: @Drew Reese You will see the error when you click on columns 11a and 11b

Comment: Oh, I see, these errors aren't showing up in the sandbox's console, but rather in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

Your `const columns = [...` array is defined outside your class, but you have callbacks, specifically your `col11aDataExpanded` and `col11bDataExpanded` callbacks that reference `this`, which is OFC undefined outside the class.  Move your `columns` definition into your class and it'll work now.

https://codesandbox.io/s/x9r93koxn4